# «Задохнуться возмущением» — правильно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Вот предложения из книг Елены Звёздной.

*— Я?.. — даже задохнулась собственным возмущением. — Я готова...* ([Игрушка императора)](http://book-online.com.ua/read.php?book=8989&page=10); *Продавщица задохнулась возмущением, фыркнула повторно, но отошла к стеллажам...* ([Мертвые игры...](https://books.google.ee/books?id=dj-IDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA283&lpg=PA283&dq=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=-9A9uWRFy8&sig=ACfU3U27LLxF9HzVz1wgcM14nkgoCOOmPg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr_93mqunjAhUpxIsKHZrjDEMQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F&f=false)); *Я задохнулась возмущением* ([Шепот в темноте](https://books.google.ee/books?id=zC85DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT26&lpg=PT26&dq=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=QKsiQNBnYb&sig=ACfU3U0VAUJB9wt_562ovjwBQx-g97zdFw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjr_93mqunjAhUpxIsKHZrjDEMQ6AEwBXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F&f=false)).

Подскажите, грамотно ли так говорить?
Я всегда считала, что правильно *задохнуться **от** возмущения* (от воспоминаний, от слез, от ненависти, от смеха, от отека, от газа — от чего?).

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что в таком контексте *нельзя* употребить глагол совершенного вида: "задохнуться" буквально означает умереть от невозможности дышать. В переносном смысле можно **говорить, задыхаясь от возмущения**. Лишнее слово здесь и "собственным" - вряд ли можно испытывать физиологические неприятности от *чужого* возмущения.

Answer (score 1):

***Задохнуться от возмущения*** можно без проблем (21 пример в Нацкорпусе):

― Ну, знаете, Мемозов! ― ***задохнулся от возмущения*** Москвич. ― [Василий Аксенов. Круглые сутки нон-стоп // «Новый Мир», 1976]

А можно ли задохнуться возмущением?

Посмотрим в словарь. Позволяется говорить так: ***задыхаться** от бега, от волнения, от жары; **задохнуться** в дыму*. Творительного падежа нет.

Но вот в текстах можно встретить выражение ***задохнуться дымом***:

Охотник подбросил в костер сырых веток, я ***задохнулся дымом***, закашлялся... [Александр Иличевский. Костер // «Октябрь», 2008]

Ну а далее авторский неологизм: ***задохнуться возмущением.***
Сочетание не кажется корректным даже в переносном значении, **звучит примитивно и грубо:** задохнуться какими-либо чувствами вряд ли возможно.

Ведь обычно речь идет **о затруднении  дыхания,** которое вызвано сильным чувством, а не о самом чувстве.

Comment: Если набрать в Гугле **_задохнулись угарным газом_** (чем?), то результат будет ошеломляющим — сотни таких высказываний. Но выходит, что так говорить неправильно? Экспертиза должна установить каким образом задохнулись угарным газом рыбаки. На Ставрополье 95-летняя бабушка задохнулась угарным газом. Супруги задохнулись угарным газом в своей квартире.  Все находившиеся в доме люди задохнулись угарным газом.

Comment: Как нестрогое, разговорное словосочетание это можно принять (задохнуться вдыхаемой субстанцией; аналогично: поперхнуться, подавиться чем-л. попавшим в горло). Фактически же при вынужденном вдыхании угарного газа происходит _отравление_ этим газом, потеря сознания и позже - остановка дыхания. Но выражение "задохнуться/задыхаться возмущением" не выдерживает критики: возмущение точно не "вдыхают", и подобная аналогия не действует. На _причину_ перебоев с дыханием можно сослаться лишь косвенно, с предлогом "от" (чего).

Comment: Почему же неверно, дымом можно надышаться, отравиться, ну и задохнуться тоже (по аналогии).  Творительный падеж не запрещен, и автор строит свое словосочетание именно по этой схеме. Но обычно сущ. в Т.п. обозначает какой-то конкретный внешний  материальный фактор, а вот сочетание "задохнуться чувством" кажется кажется неестественным и поэтому неприемлемым (извращенным, если вспомнить словечко из недавнего вопроса).